# how to load data from a json file in python?

Tags: python, json

i have some problems with JSON in python

here is my code:

```
import json

file = open("login_data.json", "r+")
lol = json.load(file)
```

and it outputs this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/python/python_code/mygame.py", line 7, in <module>
    lol = json.load(file)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/json/__init__.py", line 293, in load
    return loads(fp.read(),
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/json/__init__.py", line 357, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/json/decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/json/decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

please can you help me?

edit: this is my .json file:

```
{
    "Moha" : "MOHA"
}
```

Comment: what does your `.json` file look like? It's highly likely it's not valid JSON

Comment: This is tough to answer without a reproduceable JSON input as it might be something in your JSON file specifically

Comment: If you search with the error message you should find some SO Q&A's that will give you an idea what to look for.

Answer (score 0):

You have to open the file in read mode first, using
`file = open("filename", "r")`
after that, read the contents using
`data = file.read()`
And turn the data which is a string into a JSON object:
`lol = json.loads(data) #json.dumps() does the opposite`

Edit: json.load(file) tries to read from file object, but you want to read from the file's contents

Comment: His code to read the file is correct, the file content has an error. It's best to use `json.load(file)`.